# Как упростить вложенный if-else со swap'ом ветвей в зависимости от внешнего?

Tags: javascript, оптимизация

Заранее извиняюсь за очень глупый вопрос!
я только начинающий кодер
не могу записать одним условием вот такой код

```
    if (c) {
        if (!a && b) {
            console.log('a1');
        } 
        else {
            console.log('a2');
        }
    else {
        if (!(!a && b)) {
            console.log('a1');
        } 
        else {
            console.log('a2');
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (!c ^ (!a && b)) {
    console.log('a1');
} else {
    console.log('a2');
}
```

Условие получается следующим: `с and (not a and b) or not c and not(not a and b)`. Заменим `not c` на `x`, `(not a and b)` на `y` получим `not x and y or x and not y`, что эквивалентно `x xor y`. В итоге имеем `not c xor (not a and b)`

Вообще-то в Javascript нет логического XOR, но битовый тоже неплохо работает, при условии, что оба операнда - булевы значения

Comment: принцип правильный, но проверьте первую ветку, там `c=true`

Comment: спасибо все работает

Comment: @MiKeBu Все правильно - `a xor b == not a and b or a and not b`

Comment: @tutankhamun, да, вы правы, я ошибся, извините)

Comment: @MiKeBu Не извиняйтесь :) Ошибиться каждый может

Answer (score 2):

Превратим всё в boolean:

```
a = !!a, b = !!b, c = !!c;
```

Теперь условие превращается в

```
console.log(c === (!a && b) ? 'a1' : 'a2');
```

Если хочется отказаться от дополнительных кастов, то можно немного ещё похомичить:

```
console.log(!!c === !!(!a && b) ? 'a1' : 'a2');
console.log(!c === !(!a && b) ? 'a1' : 'a2');
console.log(!c === (!!a || !b)) ? 'a1' : 'a2');
```

Надеюсь, нигде не ошибся.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!a && b) {
    console.log('a1');
}
console.log('a2');
```

Comment: это не будет одним и тем же того что написано с верху